# Save parsed JSON data into Variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have this ajax request call to a json supported link (url1):

```
$.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     dataType : "json",
     url : url1,
     success: function (data) {
            c1lat1 = [(data[0].boundingbox[0]),(data[0].boundingbox[2])];
            alert(c1lat1);
     }
});
```

This works perfectly fine, and the alert does give the number I want. However, if I try this:

```
$.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     dataType : "json",
     url : url1,
     success: function (data) {
            c1lat1 = [(data[0].boundingbox[0]),(data[0].boundingbox[2])];
     }
});
alert(c1lat1);
```

It gives me an empty alert box, and therefore it looks like it's not saving the value into the variable into the request.

How can I get around this as I need that value retrieved?

Thanks!

Comment: I have initialized it just before the ajax call.

Comment: it's about synchronicity not scope. The ajax call by default is asynchronous. That's it, the `success` callback is **always** invoked after your `alert`

Comment: `c1lat1 ` this variable name drives me crazy...

Comment: With scope correct, you have to look at how it runs... sends the Ajax call, then calls the alert... doesn't wait for ajax to finish.

Comment: How can I get it wait then?

Comment: @Jeremy Miller: it has nothing to do with scopes. Please don't spread your personal misunderstandings. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyMiller — You're confusing definition (which doesn't matter for scope) with declaration (which does).

Comment: @Quentin Thank you.  I have removed the fallacious comment.

Comment: @Jeremy Miller: I have no idea what you're talking about. I'm making SO a better place by pointing people what they are talking is wrong. It makes sense to teach people instead of helping spreading misunderstandings. Especially when you were told twice you're wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ajax is **async** by default, you have two options-

1. Alert the variable in the callback. You must proceed after you get the result in the callback-

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     dataType : "json",
     url : url1,
     success: function (data) {
         c1lat1 = [(data[0].boundingbox[0]),(data[0].boundingbox[2])];
         alert(c1lat1);
     }
   });
   ```
2. Make the call synchronous using `async: false`, this will make your call synchronous, and the control will come after `$.ajax()`;

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     async: false,
     dataType : "json",
     url : url1,
     success: function (data) {
         c1lat1 = [(data[0].boundingbox[0]),(data[0].boundingbox[2])];
     }
   });
   alert(c1lat1);
   ```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: from documentation: `As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated`

Comment: Straight to the point. +1
Please add an explanation why your answer works, though.

Comment: @Justinas — So what? The `async: false` isn't being used with jqXHR. (SJAX is still horrible though).

Comment: Thanks, the second one worked! But is there a compatibility or deprecation issue with it?

Comment: Only with jqXHR, you can use this with your call :) PS, accept the answer if worked, so the discussion may close here.

Answer (score -2):

1) it's scope problems. c1lat1 inside `success` is local variable. Define it globaly.

2) `success` is async, so your alert happens before response from server, so no variable is set yet. move alert to `success`

Comment: It's not local. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @zerkms because i don't see it's declaration before entering Ajax

Comment: @Justinas — JavaScript doesn't work like that. It isn't declared inside the function, so the scope must be from outside the function.

Comment: @Justinas: so? There is no declaration indeed. Why do you think it's local? http://jsfiddle.net/mGNQ3/ - here is an example that might help you get that what you're stating is incorrect

Comment: Try this: `(function (){x = 1;})(); console.log(x);`
If `x` isn't explicitly declared to `a`'s scope, it's global. Scope is not the issue here.

Comment: It's my bad I haven't included the declaration; but I have indeed initialized the variable before the call.